# Practical number algorithm too slow

Tags: swift, algorithm, numbers

I am trying to write a program to find the practical numbers, from an input from 1 to n.

Practical numbers : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number

My code is running correctly but it is extremely slow - takes over 20 minutes when it should take 10 seconds. This happens when calculating numbers around 50 - it gets stuck at 44.

It is written in Swift

```
import Foundation

func getInteger() -> Int {
    var firstNum:Int = 0
    while true {
        // get value from user. Using optional input since readLine returns an optional string.
        let input = readLine()
        // ensure string is not nil
        if let unwrappedInput = input {
            if let unwrappedInt = Int(unwrappedInput) {
                firstNum = unwrappedInt
                break
            }
            else { // the input doesn't convert into an int
                print("`\(unwrappedInput)` is not an integer. Please enter an integer")
            }
        }
        else { // did not enter anything
            print("Please enter an integer")
        }
    }

    return firstNum
}
func addOne(signArray: [Int]) -> [Int] { // finds the combinations
    var signArray2 = [Int]()
    for i in 0...signArray.count-1 {
        signArray2.append (signArray[i])
    }

    for i in 0...signArray2.count-1 {
        if signArray2[i] == 1 {
            signArray2[i] = 0
        }
        else {
            signArray2[i] = 1
            break
        }
    }
    return signArray2
}
func signEval (signArray: [Int], divArray: [Int], inNum: Int) -> Bool  {// changes 2nd
  var counts = 0
    for i in 0...divArray.count-1 {
        if signArray[i] == 0 {
counts = divArray[i] + counts        }
        if counts == inNum {
            return true
        }
    }
        return false
}
print("Please enter a number to find the summable numbers up to that number:")
var input2 = getInteger()// if num = 1 print 1 if num = 2 print 1 and 2 else print >2 1, 2
var inNum = 0
var numHalf = 0.0
var numRound = 0.0
var numCheck = false
var numCheck2 = false
var numQuarter = 0.0
var numSixth = 0.0
var divArray:[Int] = []
var theirArray = [Int]()
var signArray = [Int]()// array of 0s and 1s
var summableArray:[Int] = [1,2] // need to check if num is bigger than 2!
for input in 1...input2 {
        numHalf = Double (input) / 2.0
        numRound = round(numHalf)
        if numRound == numHalf {
            numCheck = true }
        if input > 2 && numCheck == false { // odd numbers greater than one are not summable
        }
        else { // these are possible summable nums
            numQuarter = Double (input) / 4.0
            numRound = round(numQuarter)
            if numRound == numQuarter {
                numCheck = true
            }
            else {
                numCheck = false
            }
            numSixth = Double(input) / 6.0
            numRound = round(numSixth)
            if numRound == numSixth {
                numCheck2 = true }
            else { numCheck2 = false}
            if numCheck == true || numCheck2 == true {
        theirArray = []
        divArray = []
        signArray = []
        summableArray = []
for i in 1...input {
    theirArray.append (i)
    }
for i in 1...input { // creates an array of all the diviors of inputted number
    if input%i == 0 {
        divArray.append (i)
    }
}
        for j in 1...divArray.count {//
            signArray.append(0)
        }

for i in 1...input{
let x: Int = Int(pow(Double(2),Double(input-1)))// int 2 to the power of input -1
    var Boolcheck = false

    for q in 1...x-1 { // i to 2^n -1 (sequence to check)
    Boolcheck = (signEval(signArray: signArray, divArray: divArray, inNum: i))// checks
        signArray = addOne(signArray: signArray)// adding the ones to the array
        if Boolcheck == true {
        summableArray.append(i)// creates array of mini summable numbers
        break
    }
        }
   if summableArray.count == input {
      print ("\(input)")
    }
}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This should probably be posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Did you try using any of the algorithms suggested in that wikipedia page?

Comment: voting as off topic for now as you did not provide any relevant info so it is Why is dis code not working type question (even if it works).... To remedy add info like: What approach did you used. What is the bottle neck , what do you consider slow and fast. Also you should describe what practical number is (links tend to broke over time)

Comment: I updated it and put it on codereview

Comment: Posted on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158142/practical-number-algorithm.